# Angular firebase Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I've got this code and both result and error got errors :

> ERROR in src/app/login/phone/phone.component.ts(48,75): error TS7006:
>   Parameter 'result' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   src/app/login/phone/phone.component.ts(53,14): error TS7006: Parameter
>   'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.

```
 verifyLoginCode() {
        this.windowRef.confirmationResult.confirm(this.verificationCode).then(result => {

            this.user = result.user;

          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error, "Incorrect code entered?"));
      }
```

How to fix it ?

I am using angularfire2, angular5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this error is because Angular's `tsconfig.json` by default sets **noImplicitAny** flag to **true** - `"noImplicitAny": true,`. With this in place Js code is being generated, but you also get the error as the compiler cannot infer the type.

Easiest fix is `then((result: any)`

Now in your comment you mention you tried `then((result: String)`. I bet what you really meant was `then((result: string)` as `string` and `String` are **not the same**. `string` is a Javascript primitive, being created with literals - `''` or `""`, while `String` is a Javascript **object** with its prototype chain.

For future reference, you can easily check the type (if you can't know in other ways) by just console.log'inig it:

```
.then(result => {
  console.log(typeof result)
})
```

p.s. and because you do `this.user = result.user;` its obvious that `result` is not a string, but rather some ind of `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

Your typescript setup will NOT allow you to specify a variable without declaring it's type.  In this example, then method accepts a parameter "result", but doesn't say what TYPE "result" is.

Update the function as

```
.then((result: ResultType) => {
```

where `ResultType` is the proper type of whatever result is.

Additionally, in the `catch` callback, `error` was not given a type.  You'll need to change `(error =>` to `((error: SomeType) =>` as well.

It actually sounds like you might want to disable the `noImplicitAny` option in your `tsconfig` `compilerOptions`.  There are many reasons why you might NOT want to do that (it forces you to be more explicit about your types, which can be good in the long run), but if you're just experimenting or trying to learn, then you might not want the option set.

If this project is for work, or is being managed by somebody else (i.e. you're just one of many developers on the project), then you might not want to disable it, because they might want `noImplicitAny` on for their own reasons (code quality).

Comment: Whatever I wrote there --> resul: Resul, or result: String , error is the same. Please be more specific.

Comment: This is completely false. The only reason you have to specify the type is that `confirm` is `any` so there is no type information for the callback parameter `result`. In any case, this is bad advice and will hide errors. Instead the type of `windowRef` should be changed so that `windowRef.confirmationResult.confirm` has the correct type.